# Где кончается придаточное или где лучше его закрыть?

Tags: пунктуация, придаточное-предложение

> Магистраль брала свое начало у садов Боргезе, от церкви, что теперь
>   возвышается над пьяцца Испания – Пресвятой Троицы на горах /
>   Santissima-Trinità-dei-Monti, и приводила она паломника кратчайшим
>   путём от северных ворот города с пьяцца дель Пополо до папской
>   базилики Санта Мария Маджоре.

Это факультативно или строго?

Comment: Три раза перечитывал, пока понял. Зачем так усложнять жизнь читателю?

Comment: Магистраль брала свое начало у садов Боргезе, от церкви Пресвятой Троицы на горах (Santissima-Trinità-dei-Monti), что теперь возвышается над пьяцца Испания.....

Comment: Не годится. Все названия церквей через весь текст идут на косой.

Comment: Главное не косая, а порядок слов.

Comment: Брала и приводила - что менять в порядке слов?

Comment: *Церьковь такая-то, что возвышается*, а не *церковь, что возвышается —такая-то*

Comment: А, спасибо. Шлю привет автору.

Comment: Взаимно.  Кстати, я с самого начала была полностью согласна с  первым комментарием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Магистраль брала начало... и приводила она (магистраль)...*

Не приводила же церковь к папской базилике. Даже если бы приводила церковь, "она" было бы лишним для придаточного предложения. Поэтому придаточное "что..." кончается перед "и приводила". У меня в этом нет ни малейшего сомнения.

Comment: То-то зе! Это я ея нарисовала где надо! )))

Answer (score 1):

Магистраль брала свое начало у садов Боргезе **(от церкви Пресвятой Троицы на горах / Santissima-Trinità-dei-Monti, что теперь возвышается над пьяцца Испания)** и приводила она паломника кратчайшим путём от северных ворот города с пьяцца дель Пополо до папской базилики Санта Мария Маджоре.

Comment: Жасмин, это нечестный для редактора выход. )))

Comment: Почему нечестный?  Магистраль, без сомнения, приводит паломника  куда надо, но вот содержание придаточного предложения понять просто невозможно. Зачем отделять название церкви от самой церкви, что это даёт?  А к чему относится тире - об этом надо долго догадываться.

Comment: Это даёт унификацию по всему тексту, где русские и италианские названия идут на косой!

Comment: @Jasmin, вот и я о том же писал!

Comment: Да я. собственно, ориентировалась на ваш ответ. И по поводу "косой" неясно, она же у меня вроде присутствует.

Comment: Жасминушка, прости, присутствует. Прочитала "по косой". ((( Текст прочитан, осталось автору вопросу переслать! Тороплюся! Т_Т